# Get Default Browser Bookmarks, and store to text file

Tags: android, browser, bookmarks

How to get default browser bookmarks, and how to store default browser bookmarks to text files.

In this links to i got the Bookmarks URL and Label (Include all sub-folders URL and Label). Refer this link
[Get browser history and search result in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626084/get-browser-history-and-search-result-in-android)

How to get a Bookmarks URL and Label in the tree structure format.

1. Default Browser contains URL.
2. In this `BOOKMARKS` contains `URL` and `Folders` and `Sub-Folders`.
3. Each Folder contains some `URL` and `Folders`
4. How do i get the tree structure format.

For Example, How do get this tree structure format

```
BOOKMARKS (Parent Folder)
    JAVA (Child Folder)
        http://www.java2s.com/
        http://roseindia.net/
    ANDROID (Child Folder)
        ANDROIDDEVELOPER (Child Folder)
            http://developer.android.com/index.html
        https://play.google.com/store?hl=en
    http://developer.android.com
```

How do get tree structure format. Is it possible. Please Guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626084/get-browser-history-and-search-result-in-android

Comment: add permission in manifest file com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS

Comment: Sorry, I am missing uses permission in the android manifest. Thank you.

Comment: @vishwa Thanks for your information. Now i am edited my question. see my question.

Comment: I guess there is no way to get the actual folder structure of the bookmarks,  as @SathishSathish asks? It would be very useful, but I search everywhere and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 12):

Add the below to your Android Manifest file as mentioned

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get bookmarks with following code snippet -

```
static final String[] columns = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,columns, null, null, null);
query.moveToFirst();
while (query.moveToNext()) {
    String title = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
    String url = query.getString(query.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
}
```

Also you will need to give following permission in the manifest file to read them -

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

For more detail see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html)

> public static final Uri BOOKMARKS_URI
>
> A table containing both bookmarks and history items. The columns of the table are defined in **Browser.BookmarkColumns**. Reading this table requires the **READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS** permission and writing to it requires the **WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS** permission.

Comment: Code gets history too. Some code for get ONLY the BOOKMARKS?

Comment: Where is the documentation of this permission? The link leads to the Browser class; there is nothing about permissions or bookmarks there...