# WebView not showing standard browser option menu

Tags: android, browser, webview, menu, optionmenu

Good morning,
I want that when the user opens my custom WebView, when he clicks the **Menu Button**, the standard browser's menu will appear *(next, previous, share link, bookmarks, etc.)*.

How?

Here's my code:

```
   public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
        

    private static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";

    WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar loadingProgressBar, loadingTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        Shared.openedActivities.add(this);

        String url = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        
        loadingProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // this will be called on page loading progress
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                loadingProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);


            // hide the progress bar if the loading is complete
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }

        });

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Trace.w(TAG, "onDestroy()");

        Shared.unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rootWebViewActivity));
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but that won't work, you have to implement this features by yourself. WebView is not the Browser, it is just a View to render Webpages. Everything else is a function of the Browser-App not the WebView. 
Nevertheless you can access the bookmarks of the browser as described here: [Get browser history and search result in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626084/get-browser-history-and-search-result-in-android)

Comment: ah :-( But maybe there is a snippet written in the past by someone. I think that a lot of people had my problem before me... right?